# Can I monitor active user count on my iis sites?

Tags: windows-server-2008, monitoring, iis-7.5, performance-monitoring

We are having problems with performance on our server that host our websites that the processor gets upp to 90%. I would like to monitor the amount of users active on your sites that are published on the iis. My question, is this possible? is there any software for this?

**EDIT**
current (like this second) visitor count on all the active websites on our iis

**REASON FOR THIS**
 if i can get the visitor amount on the days the CPU is not overloaded and and compare it to the days it is then i atleast know that this **CAN** be a reason why this is happening and i can take it from there. Otherwise i can focus on the code on the sites, or maybe google crawler is causing this, there are manythings that can cause this you know? for me this is just a simple way of troubleshooting.

Comment: How is knowing the number of active users/connections going to help you resolve the CPU utilization problem?

Comment: Step 1: Define "user".

Comment: @womble Website visitor

Comment: Step 2: Define "Website visitor".  Seriously, it is *very* hard to accurately capture what set of requests constitute one visitor.  Most people stick with a much simpler metric like "page views".

Comment: @joeqwerty maybe the "visitor rate" is to much for the amount of cpu amount that we got on the server. its not just this issue its good to have that for other situtations as well.

Comment: @womble do we got a way to get the page views then on all of the websites published on a iis? i got like 20 sites, google analytics is not a option

Comment: Again, how are you going to correlate the number of visitors to the CPU utilization? How will you know how many visitors is too many? Is there a metric or formula for calculating that? It's like asking how many bunnies can be supported by x number of carrots, without knowing how many carrots a single bunny consumes.

Comment: Simply counting the number of visitors gets you no closer to a solution and the only thing it's going to tell you is how many concurrent visitors there are. Knowing the number of visitors and correlating that to actual CPU utilization requires a much more in depth analysis.

Comment: Its called monitoring for a reason, we got days that our cpu is not that active and other days it is. now if i can get the visitor amount on the days its not and on the days it is then i atleast know that this CAN be a reason why this is happening and i can take it from there. If the visitor amount is the same all the time and the CPU is overloading then i can move on and try to run through the code and se if something is causing this..

Comment: @joeqwerty great help you are buddy, if you got any better ideas please share them to troubleshoot easy then be my guest and tell me, i dont got thousends of dollars to spend, some time you just got to be creative and think logical and find simple solutions to find problems.

Comment: Dejan: I'm trying to be helpful by pointing out that counting the number of users isn't going to directly correlate to the CPU utilization problem that you're seeing. It's too simplistic to take the approach that "I need x CPU for y users" without understanding the underlying reason. My approach would be to analyze the CPU utilization per process and work from there rather than counting users and trying to correlate that to the problem. You may resolve the symptoms of the problem by throwing more CPU at it based on the number of users but that might leave you with an unresolved root cause.

Comment: @Dejan.S You can look at concurrent connections but concurrent connections has no bearing on the number of people viewing the website or their usage of the server. For most modern browsers the number of default connections to a server is 6.  In order to get meaningful results by that inference you'd have to capture quite a long period of time (I would expect 6 months at a minimum), since user count bears no direct relation to usage.

Comment: @joeqwerty did not sound like that. Thanks for the info tho ill look into that, i apprecite it i really do.

Comment: IIS can log every request and you can do statistics based on it, but probably your load isn't because of the request count, rather than something cpu-heavy user action and/or a bad, often running code or some l

Answer (score 1):

This isn't an exact count for how many users are currently on the site, but it's a metric that we consider close enough for what you're after. We use the performance counter 'Web Service\Current Connections'.

When a user initially hits your site their browser will most likely open up 5 or 6 connections but that will probably settle down to 1 once they've loaded the images/scripts etc (that's what we've found anyway).

Comment: powershell script to get current value per iis web site: http://poshcode.org/1146

Answer (score 0):

You can turn on IIS Request Tracing, and/or monitor Worker Processes under Health and Diagnostics (if you're using W2K8/IIS7x) and combined with detailed logging being enabled, should tell you how many requests you're currently serving and the logging (with a W3C log parser, Google it) will give you an aggregate over a period of time.

If you're using IIS 6/Windows 2003, you can use perfmon and add whatever IIS-related counters you want and leave it running.

Answer (score 0):

If this is iis7 you can try using appcmd.

%systemroot%\system32\inetsrv\APPCMD list requests

http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/getting-started-with-iis/getting-started-with-appcmdexe#Finding

It will show active iis connections.

II6 has a vbs script called iisweb.vbs that did similar. I've never used it so I don't know where it's located.

iisweb.vbs /query

https://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/1805162e-6ac5-4a98-9a08-919c4c10827d.mspx?mfr=true